# Proving Maxwell's equation, divergence of $E$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, gauss-law

For a sourceless medium perturbed as shown below, how can I prove that divergence of $\vec E$ and $\vec H$ equal to zero?

$$\vec D = \varepsilon \vec E -j \xi \vec B$$

$$\vec H = \dfrac{1}{\mu} \vec B -j \xi \vec E$$

My initial intuition was finding this by applying a vector identity.

$$\nabla\times\nabla\times \vec E = \nabla (\nabla \bullet \vec E)-\nabla^2 \vec E$$

We know Maxwell's equations for a sourceless medium as
$$\nabla \times \vec E = -j\omega \vec B$$
and
$$\nabla \times \vec H = j\omega \vec D$$

For deriving for the $ \vec E$ field, we know the wave equation as $\nabla\times\nabla\times \vec E-2\mu\omega\xi \nabla\times \vec E-\omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \vec E = 0$

So, $\nabla (\nabla \bullet \vec E)-\nabla^2 \vec E-2\mu\omega\xi \nabla\times \vec E-\omega^2 \mu \varepsilon \vec E = 0$

As we found the divergence term, we should be able to prove $\nabla\bullet \vec E =0$.

How can I derive the rest of the problem?

Comment: First two equations are not Maxwell's. They are constitutive relations. You can see Maxwell's at 7th line. @Drjh

Comment: Do $\mu$ and $\xi$ depend on space? If not, what about taking divergence to the second constitutive relation? Because there $\vec H$ is a linear combination of two vectors with divergence equal to zero.

Comment: Dr jh, I think this are the resulting Maxwell's equations when you use the ansatz that the fields depend on time by a factor $exp(j\omega t) $.

Comment: Actually, the above equations seem dimensionsally correct. These are called the phasor forms of the MEs. The time derivatives are replaced with $j\omega$.

Comment: I didn't wanted to bring phasors to the discussion for not make more confusion but yes, that's the correct terminology.

Comment: In your equation involving the vector identity, you should have  obtained $\nabla \times \nabla \times E = -\nabla^2 E$ since $\nabla \cdot E = 0$.

Comment: Why do you want to prove that $\nabla \cdot E = 0$ ?This is obviously true since there are no sources. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric field at any arbitrary point $\mathcal{r}$ due to a charge density $\rho$ present in a given volume $\mathcal{V}$ is given by Coulomb's law as -
$$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int_{\mathcal{V}}\frac{\rho\ \hat{r} }{r^2} d\tau$$

We will evaluate the surface integral of the $\vec{E}$ over a sphere containing the source charges.
$$\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{a} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int\frac{\rho\ \hat{r} }{r^2} \cdot r^2\sin (\theta)\ d\phi\ d\theta\ \hat{r}\ d\tau$$
or, $$\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{a} = \int\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}d\tau$$
Invoking Fundamental theoram of gradient -
$$\int \nabla \cdot \vec{E}\ d\tau = \oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{a}$$
So,$$\int \nabla \cdot \vec{E}\ d\tau = \int\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}d\tau$$
Since this is true for any given volume , thus we get -
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
Now in a charge free region $\rho = 0 $ so you get $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 0$.
A similar exercise with Biot-Savart law will give you the desired result for the magnetic field.